# The men quarreled among themselves

Tags: prepositions

**The men quarreled among themselves.**

If there are more than two men, "among" is OK. But what if there are two men.

**The men quarreled among/between themselves. ???**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy just cut it.  If there are two men the quarrel must be between the two men. So just remove that part altogether!

> The (two) men quarrelled.

If you desperately *need* something there, use "with each other".

Comment: It's a theoretical question.

Comment: Ain't no such thing on ELL.  Nobody learns English *in theory*.  There is no hypothetical English that we can model, even if it does not exist in reality.

Comment: It's just one man's opinion, not mine. I never speak for everyone and advise against it.